# 415 Unsupported Media Type, when NOT sending an optional request body with POST request

Tags: http-post, spring-restcontroller, spring-web

I have a REST controller that defines an interface which takes an optional request body.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ExampleRest.EXAMPLE_URI)
public class ExampleRest {
    public static final String EXAMPLE_URI = "/examples";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = POST)
    public Page<ExampleDto> search(@RequestBody(required = false) Searchable searchable, Pageable pageable) {
        return exampleService.findAll(searchable, pageable);
    }
}
```

The `Searchable` object contains information to create a `JPASpecification`. It's pretty much a `dto`. I would like to make this searchable optional. I understood that `@RequestBody(required = false)` should do the trick.

I have the following test, where I want to test a request without any request body.

```
@Test
public void post_NoCriteria_Ok() {
    RequestEntity requestEntity = new RequestEntity(HttpMethod.POST, URI.create(ExampleRest.EXAMPLE_URI + "/search"));
    ResponseEntity <RestResponsePage<ExampleDto>> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference <RestResponsePage<ExampleDto>> () {});
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
}
```

If I run this test, it keeps failing with this response from the `RestController`:

> <415 Unsupported Media Type,Page 1 of 1 containing UNKNOWN
>   instances,{Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8],
>   Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:10:22 GMT]}>

The Code execution does not even enter `search` method implementation inside of the `RestController`.

As soon I provide an empty `Searchable` for the test, it runs through.

Is the implementation of `@RequestBody(required = false)` buggy, or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Content-Type` as `"application/json"` in your request while sending from `@Test` file.